# skip first parameter in File.join

Tags: ruby

I want to make a path by using File.join but how can I skip the first argument if it's null or how can I write this code without using If statement

```
image_files_path =
  if options.path.nil?
    File.join('**', '*.jpg')
  else
    File.join(options.path, '**', '*.jpg')
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget that Ruby can *splat* arguments, so this is actually pretty easy. You can either selectively add it:

```
args = %w[ ** *.jpg ]

if (options.path)
  args.unshift(options.path)
end

File.join(*args)
```

Or you can just put it in by default and strip it out if it's `nil`:

```
File.join(*[ options.path, '**', '*.jpg' ].compact)
```

It's important to note that the only things in Ruby that are logically false are `nil` and `false` so a test for `nil?` is only required if it's possible that value might be literal `false`. If that's not the case a regular `if` will suffice.

Comment: @mudasobwa They should [really document that](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/File.html#method-c-join) then.

Comment: That’s a secret weapon.

Comment: @mudasobwa I hope it's not DLC I have to unlock by beating a boss!

Comment: What about `File.join(*options.path, '**', '*.jpg')`?